# Is there a way to fix internationalization inconsistencies in Google Places API calls?

Tags: search, internationalization, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Places API for my project and I found that different places will have different localized names in their address components.

For instance:

- some places in Lisbon (Portugal) will have a `locality` name of `Lisbon` while others will have `Lisboa`.
- some places in Barcelona will have a `administrative_area_level_1` name of `Catalonia`, while others will have `Catalunya`.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to get consistent results using a same reference language?
2. Is there a way to help Google fix this inconsistent behavior?

ps: my purpose it to be able to perform text-based search from Google Places API data, and these localization differences are not helping.

Answer (score 1):

This may be working as intended, or an inconsistency in how some places have their address registered on Google Maps.

It is the intended behavior that the local language (Lisbon, Cataluña) is used for street-level addresses, while the user's preferred language is used for the other places (postal codes and political entites). Reverse geocoding while preferring non-local language shows this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&latlng=38.716322,-9.149895&language=en

1. `street_address`: R. Cecílio de Sousa 84, 1200-009 **Lisboa**, Portugal
2. `locality`: **Lisbon**, Portugal

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&latlng=41.738528,1.851196&language=en

1. `street_address`: C-16C, 2, 08243 Manresa, Barcelona (**Cataluña**), Spain
2. `postal_code`: 08243 Manresa, Barcelona (**Catalunya**), Spain

(Cataluña/Catalunya/Catalonia is not usually in `formatted_address`)

However, there may be addresses that were registered without correctly linking to the appropriate political entities, e.g. using "Catalonia" as a hard-coded address component instead of as a reference to the administrative_area_level_1 itself. These would appear with inconsistent names, even for street-level addresses. Such should be rare, but please consider [filing a bug](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=188871&template=788907) when found.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, in your Manresa/Barcelona example, for instance, the fact that the `administrative_area_level_1` part of the `address_components` refers to **Catalonia** for the results of type `administrative_area_level_4`, `administrative_area_level_2` and `administrative_area_level_1`, but refers to **Catalunya** for the results of type `administrative_area_level_3` is a bug? (as **Catalonia** is the right English word, it should also be used for `administrative_area_level_3`)

Comment: Maybe. For each result, all address components are all returned in the same language (except for country), which is chosen from the first component. If the first component is not available in the exact language that is requested, then a similar language is used. In the case of administrative_area_level_3 "El Bages" it looks like that name is only available in Calatan, hence the Catalunya (instead of Catalonia) name is used.